# what is the top level code and normal code for drawing an "ellipse" in swift

Tags: swift

I would like to draw an ellipse in the playground.
top level codes are the codes used to write in playgrounds to make coding simpler. 
I would know drawing an ellipse in normal mode also

Answer (score 0):

```
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(59, 28, 123, 50))
UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
ovalPath.fill()
```

use the code importing `UIKit`.

You can change values accordingly.